# Symfony Call to a member function guessExtension()

Tags: symfony

I try to upload a file on my entity but i get actually

> Call to a member function guessExtension() on array

the problem come from this line on my controller :

> $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

Someone know why i'm getting this error ? hope someone could help me to resolve the problem. thanks a lot in advance

Best regards

Here my entity :

```
class Gig
{

    private $flyer;

 public function setFlyer($flyer)
    {
        $this->flyer = $flyer;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getFlyer()
    {
        return $this->flyer;
    }

...
```

Here my controller :

```
public function addGigAction(Request $request , $id ){

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $artist = $em->getRepository('BookingRoosterBundle:artist')->find($id);

        if (null === $artist) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("L'annonce d'id ".$id." n'existe pas.");
        }

        $gig = new Gig();
        //on inject l'artist directement
        $gig->setArtist($artist);

        $form = $this->createForm(GigType::class, $gig);


        if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {

            $file = $gig->getFlyer();

            $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

            $file->move(
                $this->getParameter('upload_directory'),
                $fileName
            );

            $gig->setFlyer($fileName);

            $em->persist($gig);
            $em->flush();

            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Date bien ajouté pour l\'artiste');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('booking_rooster_view', array(
                'id' => $artist->getId()
            ));
        }

        return $this->render('BookingRoosterBundle:Artist:addGig.html.twig' , array(
            'artist' => $artist,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));

    }
```

Here my dump from $file :

```
array(1) { ["file"]=> object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#37 (7) { ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> bool(false) ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> string(38) "techno_flyer_by_curtismack-d4lbtu5.png" ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> string(9) "image/png" ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(243010) ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(0) ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(45) "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpdfJ98s" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(9) "phpdfJ98s" } }
```

Comment: wher do comme your `$gig->getFlyer()` ? and have you done a dump of your $file  ?

Comment: yes i did a dump ! i make an update of the post with the dump result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i still don't know where do you set the values that you got in the `getFlyer()` but it seems that you have an array here, simply do something like this :

```
$fileArray = $gig->getFlyer();
$file = $fileArray['file'];
$fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
```

Comment: @MathieuMourareau It will be worth fixing the real cause of this issue. Your issue is that when you're calling `setFlyer()`, you are passing in an `array`. Try fixing it before setting the flyer.

Comment: how could i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a setter and getter like this, this is how the symfony entity builder creates it:

```
public function getHeader(): ?string {}
public function setHeader(?string $header): self {}
```

The error is because [you cast the result to string](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/26750#issuecomment-378136143), removing the typehinting fixed it:

```
public function getHeader(){}
public function setHeader($header): self {}
```